# Como repetir la solicitud de una api con distintas id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

estoy aprendiendo a utilizar React con Axios y se me ocurrió generar toda la Pokedex (Con la PokeAPI), pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo, ya hice varias cosas y por el momento la idea que se me habia ocurrido es la siguiente:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'





class HomeContainer extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        var idCambiante = 1;
        for (let index = 1; index < 151; index++) {
            idCambiante = idCambiante + 1;
        } //Aca se me habia ocurrido hacer una id Cambiante que suba su numero del 1 al 151,


            console.log(idCambiante)
            axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${idCambiante}') //Solicitud api
            .then(result=>{
                // console.log(result)
                //console.log('aaa', result.data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default)
                
                var items = {
                    nombre: result.data.name,
                    imagen: result.data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default,
                }
                
                
                construir(result, idCambiante) //Exportamos el resultado a la funcion construir
                //En la funcion construir, genero los pokemon y las imagenes 
                
            }) 

        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error) //Solicitud error
        })
    }
    
    render(){ //Renderizamos el html
        return(
            <h1>Pokedex</h1>
            );
    }
}

const construir = (id, idCambiante) => {
    console.log(id)

    for (let index = 1; index < 151; index++) {
        idCambiante = idCambiante + 1        
        
        
    }
    return(
        idCambiante
        );
}
 
export default HomeContainer
```

Básicamente es un For del 1 al 151, dentro de ese for una variable que empieza en 1 y termina en 151, cuando meto la solicitud de la API dentro del for me tira un error grande, y también quise exportar en la función construir la id cambiante pero no funciono, me quede sin ideas, si pueden ayudarme les agradeceré eternamente!.

(Si alguien quiere decirme buenas practicas con React y Axios estaré ETERNAMENTE agradecido también!)

Comment: Dentro del ciclo `for` solo actualizas la variable, que no es necesaria. Simplemente coloca la petición AJAX (axios) dentro del ciclo y usa `i` en lugar de `idCambiante` para incluir en la URL.

Comment: Pero como haria eso? Si i solo cambia dentro del ciclo for

Comment: Osea, por i nos referimos a index, verdad?

Comment: Sí, perdón por la confusión, es `index`

Comment: Pero como haria? Index entra en el for valiendo 1 y dentro del for alcanza el valor 151, pero la peticion axios la tengo fuera del for

Comment: Precisamente, la petición debe estar dentro del `for`, porque así como la tienes, se ejecuta solo una vez.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, gracias

Comment: Me sirve ponerlo dentro del for, pero el problema es que cuando pongo ${index}, me salen muchos errores: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Comment: creo que seria mejor idea una paginacion, traes, por ejemplo, 15 datos iniciales, si el usuario quiere seguir viendo ira a la siguiente pagina, ahi haces otra peticion, asi sucesivamente

Comment: Entonces deberia hacer la peticion 15 veces??

Comment: 151/15=10.066... necesitas hacer la petición 11 veces. La api tiene parámetros para realizar la paginación. Te dejo el enlace:  https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#resource-listspagination-section

Comment: gracias por el enlace, pero no entiendo como hacer para generarlo esas veces, es decir, yo hago la peticion a la url, pero no se como hacer para repetirla esa cantidad de veces